# After switching to Swift3 I have: Type NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element (aka Any) has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray, swift3

this is actually a follow up to this question: [how can I convert NSArray into specific String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031802/how-can-i-convert-nsarray-into-specific-string/40031939#40031939) Bryan's answer worked for me in previous version of Swift, but now when I moved to `Swift 3`, this code:

```
if (defaults.object(forKey: "fb_friends") != nil) {
    var friends = (defaults.objectForKey("fb_friends") as! NSMutableArray)
                    .map{$0["id"]!!}
                    .joinWithSeparator(",")
                friends+=",\(defaults.stringForKey("facebookId")!)"
                params["friends"] = friends 
            }
```

and especially this line `.map{$0["id"]!!}` throws me an error:

```
Type NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element (aka Any) has no subscript members
```

what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear that you can no longer to access subscript members from `Any` in Swift 3.

In this case, you can cast it to `NSDictionary`.

```
var friends = (defaults.objectForKey("fb_friends") as! NSArray)
    .map{($0 as! NSDictionary)["id"] as! String}
    .joined(separator: ",")
```